# Why is there no third option of signature for decorating computationally-intensive asynchronous task-returning functions

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

### TL;DR

Why, in addition to the synchronous and *truly* asynchronous naming conventions (e.g. `SomeMethod()` and `SomeMethodAsync()`), was there no recommended naming convention for computationally-intensive functions that could similarly be performed asynchronously and awaited?

Instead of an `-Async` suffix, it could have been `-AsyncCPU`, `-Threaded`, `-Awaiting`, `-Tasked`, etc...

### Context

Coming to the C# asynchrony game a bit late, I finally started to grasp the how's and why's of asynchronously performing computationally-intensive tasks since `async` and `await` were introduced after I read [this post by Stephen Cleary](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html).

The pertinent bits I got from it were a clarification that, when exposing an API, one should expose synchronous functions with a standard naming style:

```
public MyDataType GetCalculatedResult(List<InputDataType> data);
```

and should expose *truly* asynchronous, but otherwise equivalent functions *(those that wait for some other process to complete)* by appending `Async` to the method name and returning `Task` or `Task<T>` as appropriate:

```
public async Task<MyDataType> GetCalculatedResultAsync(List<InputDataType> data);
```

...using `await` for whatever you're *actually waiting* on *(in this case, perhaps a web service that does the calculation for me)*, thus letting any thread handling be set up elsewhere.

Alternately, if you have a CPU-bound algorithm you want to run asynchronously *(it might perhaps perform a certain calculation locally instead of using a web service)*, one should not put that in a method decorated as `Async`, because it's not *truly* async. It would, however, be advantageous to run it somewhere other than e.g. the UI thread. So, one should expose it *only* as a synchronous function, and allow the programmer using it to specify which thread it runs in:

```
private async void HandleUIRequestForCalculation(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myDataInstance = await Task.Run(() => myService.GetCalculatedResult(inputDataList));
}
```

The primary argument I've seen for doing this is that it's easy enough for the programmer to do directly, and moreover that exposing it as synchronous is not as potentially confusing to those that might assume it is *truly* asynchronous. The name implies something to most consumers that is not true.

### Question

If it's basically just to avoid confusion, why couldn't there be a third recommended naming convention for computationally-intensive functions that could be performed asynchronously and awaited, like `-Threaded`, `-AsyncCPU`, `-Awaiting`, `-Tasked`, etc.?

Does this not make sense for some reason I've yet to grok? When building your API, if the implemented process was something that could be truly asynchronous, you expose the synchronous `DoSomething()` and the asynchronous `DoSomethingAsync()`, but if it's merely computationally intensive, you'd expose the synchronous `DoSomething()` and the asynchronous `DoSomethingThreaded()`.

Similar to how `-Async` instantly conveys the fact that this is something that can be awaited while it sits and waits for whatever *it's waiting for*, something like `-Threaded` could instantly convey that this is something that is intensive and can easily be awaited while it chews through whatever it's gnawing on.

Answer (score 1):

> The primary argument I've seen for doing this is that it's easy enough for the programmer to do directly, and moreover that exposing it as synchronous is not as potentially confusing to those that might assume it is truly asynchronous. The name implies something to most consumers that is not true.

While that's true, it's also very important for ASP.NET apps to *avoid* `Task.Run`. On ASP.NET, `Task.Run` completely removes all the benefits of `await` and in fact makes the performance and scalability of the web app even worse than a straight synchronous call.

So, synchronous code *should* be called with `Task.Run` from the UI thread, but should *not* be called with `Task.Run` from ASP.NET request threads.

Comment: I understood that well enough from your linked blog post, and is why you recommend not exposing a method that uses `Task.Run()` as an `-Async` method. It implies something to most users that's not true. But this doesn't answer my query: why not have an alternate recommendation that would just as clearly indicate it's using `Task.Run()` - anyone writing something for ASP.Net would see it's not called `DoSomethingAsync` and call the `DoSomething` method instead. They would also then name their method e.g. `CallDoSomethingThreaded` instead of `CallDoSomething` or `CallDoSomethingAsync`

Comment: @CodeJockey: I don't see where the big benefit is of having a `Threaded` method at all. It would really only be useful when doing a single CPU-bound operation from a UI thread; alternatively, the consumer may want to call it via `Parallel`, and `Task.Run` would interfere with that.

Comment: I suppose your answer, then, would be "It wasn't worth it"? calling via `Parallel`, again, would simply call `DoSomething` because there's no `DoSomethingAsync` (??)

Comment: My idea of the potential benefit is simply cleaner code. the API designer could also determine in this `-Threaded` method whether to make a `Task` or `Parallel` call or some other such thread handling, based upon the data provided  and perhaps the nature of the object represented by the API - nobody is forcing the API consumer to use _any_ asynchrony, it's simply a convention that is added for convenience. If it's desired to micromanage the calling of `DoSomething()`, that is still very very possible.

Comment: also, thanks for your blog post

Comment: @CodeJockey: Yes, my opinion (and just my opinion) is that it wouldn't be worth it.

Comment: [from Stephen Taub](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx): "This has all been a very long-winded way of saying that I believe the only asynchronous methods that should be exposed are those that have scalability benefits over their synchronous counterparts.  Asynchronous methods should not be exposed purely for the purpose of offloading: such benefits can easily be achieved by the consumer of synchronous methods using functionality specifically geared towards working with synchronous methods asynchronously, e.g. Task.Run." -- apparently there's consensus :-)